# Secure Web Socket connection on ejabberd

Tags: ssl, websocket, ejabberd

I am running ejabberd 17.12. 
It works fine.

With this config, I manage to open non-secure web socket connections to it from my browser using both the JS console and a XMPP client :

```
port: 5280
ip: "::"
module: ejabberd_http
request_handlers:
  "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws
  "/bosh": mod_bosh
  "/api": mod_http_api
##  "/pub/archive": mod_http_fileserver
web_admin: true
## register: true
captcha: false
```

I need to have secure web socket connections working, so I added this to the above configuration :

```
tls: true
certfile: "/opt/ejabberd/conf/server.pem"
```

Now web socket connections don't work anymore, even unsecured ones. When I try to open one, I still see this in `ejabberd.log` :

> [info] <0.4280.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:302 (<0.4489.0>) Accepted connection ::ffff:127.0.0.1:58410 -> ::ffff:127.0.1.1:5280

I get nothing into `error.log`. In the browser's JS console I see :

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://domain.local:5280/ws/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

Again, my setup works fine for unsecure web socket connections when I remove the following two lines from `ejabberd.yml` :

```
tls: true
certfile: "/opt/ejabberd/conf/server.pem"
```

The path to the certificate is correct, and `server.pem` is the default one that came when I installed ejabberd.

I am not so sure how to move forward from here. 
Any suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: I'm facing this exact issue. Any update from your side?

Answer (score 0):

Try with **wss**://domain.local:5280/ws/ connection it will work. You got error because **tls: true** in ejabberd configuration file